# How to retain the interactive shell after bash -c completes?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a toy script which prints out `$SHLVL` and shell invocation settings:

```
$ cat tst.sh 
echo "Level: $SHLVL"
echo "Options: $-"
```

If I `source` it in the current shell it works as expected:

```
$ source tst.sh 
Level: 1
Options: himBHs
```

If it's `sourced` in the sub-shell, again nothing too exciting:

```
$ /bin/bash
$ source tst.sh 
Level: 2
Options: himBHs
```

Running it with the `-c` setting gave me slightly different output:

```
$ /bin/bash -c 'source tst.sh'
Level: 2
Options: hBc
```

Therefore I've supplied the missing options:

```
$ /bin/bash -sic 'source tst.sh'
Level: 2
Options: himBHcs
```

Note that every time I have `sourced` my script using the `-c` setting, after completion of the last command in the script the sub-shell has exited. This is something I would like to prevent, thus after the last command in the script I should remain in the `interactive` sub-shell.

Basically I would like to replicate the following sequence of steps, but using `-c`:

```
$ /bin/bash
$ source tst.sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe simpler than it looks:

```
bash --init-file tst.sh
```

or

```
bash --rcfile tst.sh
```

Comment: It's probably worth to mention that it's not an exact equivalent of those two steps that I've tried to replicate. Just by calling the `/bin/bash` I enter the interactive shell, which means that `~/.bashrc` is 
sourced during the invocation. If I provide the `--rcfile` flag, then `~/.bashrc` is no longer sourced, instead the file following the flag is sourced (which may or may not be a problem, for instance my `$PS1` may look different). To address this my `tst.sh` probably should include the line similar to following: `case "$-" in *i*) [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && source "$HOME/.bashrc"; esac`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the `--init-file` idea, this will let you press Up + Enter to rerun the command from history:

```
echo 'pwd; ls' >/tmp/hist
HISTFILE=/tmp/hist bash --init-file /tmp/hist
```